# Inline css add style issue

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

I have created Two Equal Columns on the page, I don't want to use Internal CSS. So that, I add `box-sizing: border-box;` in the inline CSS, below is my coding:

```html
<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
  <div class="column" style="float: left;width: 50%;padding: 10px;height: 300px;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="float: left;width: 50%;padding: 10px;height: 300px;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the result is shown like below:

[image: output]

Actually, I want the output like below:

[image: result]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: box-sizing on the elements not their parent

Comment: @Temani Afif Ok. So how to add in the inline style?

Comment: I don't think that this question should've been closed or quoted as a [duplicate]. Well instead of using floats, Use `display: flex;` on the row class : 
`.row{
  display: flex;
}`

Comment: @RudyTheWebDev automatically using display:flex everywhere is the worst answer. You are hiding the issue under another issue and the OP will understand nothing.

Comment: Ok. Thanks your answer.